# Send anonymous request to Windows authenticated server

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have an IIS website on localhost which is configured to use Windows authentication.

I would like to send an anonymous (unauthenticated) request to it, but all connections seem to be authenticated.

For example, if I run `curl` as follows:

```
curl -v 'http://localhost:61057/MyApp'
```

Then curl prints its full set of headers, none of which are authentication related:

```
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 61057 (#0)
> GET /MyApp HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (i686-pc-cygwin) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8t zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.22 libssh2/1.3.0
> Host: localhost:61057
> Accept: */*
```

... but the web server still has my windows username in the `Context.User.Identity.Name` variable when answering the request.

Is the NTLM authentication sent in the transport layer somehow? Is there any way to turn it off for a given request?